# Following an execv() call with Qt Creator's debugger

Tags: c, linux, gdb, qt-creator, wine

I am trying to debug an application (`wine`, to name it) with Qt Creator's debugger. However, at some point, there is a call to `execv`, and I can't step into the program anymore.

I have tried to use `set follow-exec-mode new` and `set follow-fork-mode child`, with some breakpoints on the `main` function(s), to no help, even though it works fine with the `gdb` command-line interface.

Is there a way to make QtCreator follow the call to another executable?

I am using:

- Qt Creator 4.3.0
- gdb 8.0
- The program I am trying to debug is compiled with gcc 7.1.1, flags `-ggdb3 -Og`

Comment: Have you tried to break on libc functions, including `__libc_start_main`? As far as my experience such breakpoints apply even after an `execve` occurs, which may help. Anyway, could you make it clear what `execv`'ed what?

Comment: Wine's architecture is a bit specific, and it bypasses the libc initialization routines in some places, because it needs to reserve some memory regions. I tried it, but it didn't work (at least with Qt Creator). The specific code is located [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/wine/code/ci/master/tree/libs/wine/config.c#l488). It is the first `execv` occurrence, where the preloader is started, which then starts the wineserver, loads the various dll.so, and starts the `.exe` code. But I would like not to get too wine-specific. Knowing how to follow an `exec` call in Qt creator would be interesting.

Comment: I just mentioned the most easily available one, without much reinventing the wheels :) Seems `wine-preloader` and `wine64-preloader` are static executable... I don't know how Qt Creator debugger is, so I assume it is gdb. You can write plugins for gdb that helps specifically for wine (as wine itself is specific, right?)

Comment: It seems that you can recompile wine. Then how about: add to the beginning of main function of `wine-preloader`: `if(getenv("debug"))raise(SIGTRAP);` that forces a breakpoint to happen?

Comment: Well, there are two problems here: I am not too gdb-savvy, and it looks like its behavior is slightly different within Qt Creator. It seems that setting `catch exec` gets me what I want, although I can't explain why... I will also keep the `if(getenv("debug"))raise(SIGTRAP);` in mind.